# How to add a line beneath the header output provided by the column tool?

Tags: bash, string-formatting

I have a short Bash script that outputs the mounted devices on the system:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
   regex="^(\/dev\S+) \S+ (\/\S+) \S+ (\S+)"

   echo "Device Mount Type"
   mount | pcregrep -o1 -o2 -o3 --om-separator=" " "$regex" | sort
}  | column -t -o" | "
```

My output is:

```
Device         | Mount     | Type
/dev/md1       | /boot/efi | vfat
/dev/md2       | /boot     | xfs
/dev/md4       | /home     | xfs
/dev/md5       | /data     | xfs
/dev/nvme0n1p2 | /tmp      | xfs
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Device         | Mount     | Type
---------------+-----------+-----
/dev/md1       | /boot/efi | vfat
/dev/md2       | /boot     | xfs
/dev/md4       | /home     | xfs
/dev/md5       | /data     | xfs
/dev/nvme0n1p2 | /tmp      | xfs
```

This is difficult because the width of the columns varies and that the very last column does not have a delimiter at the end.

The width of the first two columns can be determined from the first line. But the width of the last column can only be determined by evaluating every line and finding the widest.

What are some simple ways to accomplish this?

Comment: you mean, `findmnt` ?

Comment: `findmnt` is a different command. The question is about `mount`.

Answer (score 0):

As a pure bash solution, please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxlen=0
lines=()
while read -r line; do
    sub1=${line%%|*}}
    s1=${#sub1}
    sub2=${line%|*}
    s2=${#sub2}
    if ((${#line} > maxlen)); then
        maxlen=${#line}
    fi
    lines+=("$line")
done < <(
{
   regex="^(\/dev\S+) \S+ (\/\S+) \S+ (\S+)"

   echo "Device Mount Type"
   mount | pcregrep -o1 -o2 -o3 --om-separator=" " "$regex" | sort
}  | column -t -o" | ")

f1=$((s1-1))            # field width for "Device"
f2=$((s2-s1))           # field width for "Mount"
f3=$((maxlen-s2-1))     # field width for "Type"

echo "${lines[0]}"
printf "%*s+" "$f1" | tr " " "-"
printf "%*s+" "$f2" | tr " " "-"
printf "%*s\n" "$f3" | tr " " "-"
for ((i=1; i<${#lines[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${lines[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
Device         | Mount     | Type
---------------+-----------+-----
/dev/md1       | /boot/efi | vfat
/dev/md2       | /boot     | xfs
/dev/md4       | /home     | xfs
/dev/md5       | /data     | xfs
/dev/nvme0n1p2 | /tmp      | xfs
```

I'd admit it will be more elegant and legible to make use other language as Cyrus.